# Create new column of unique values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hana

I have the following table and I need to create new column "index tot new" from other available columns in order to have only unique values:

[image]

Comment: How do you decide which row to assign a unique value?

Comment: will category data and order remain the same for every group? I mean saf, env, qual, hr.

Comment: I doesn't matter which row to assign a unique value.

Comment: >will category data and order remain the same for every group? I mean saf, env, qual, hr. -> YES

Comment: I wonder why you would wish to do this.

Comment: @Porridge if this category data and order can be the same then you can select unique for every group and can join with the main result set. Is it related to SQL Server or MySQL? Please share the create table and insert script for this.

Comment: 'I doesn't matter which row to assign a unique value' - it does since there appears to be no way of establishing unique row by index total - unless category does so?

Comment: What is the goal? ```SELECT DISTINCT `index tot` FROM ..``` is more simple.

Comment: Hi, sorry my fault.. I wasn't clear enough. I can't use SELECT DISTINCT `index tot` FROM .. since I need to keep the integrity with primary key "date,nation,contract,supplier,type1" and moreover if I have two same values I'll lost this information.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question is that you want to add a generated ID column to an arbitrary table.

Let's as an example take your data structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tab 
(
    date varchar(6), 
    contract varchar(5), 
    nation varchar(2), 
    supplier varchar(20), 
    type1 varchar(4), 
    type2 varchar(1), 
    category varchar(10), 
    cat_weight integer,
    index_tot integer
);

INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('202101', '8400A', 'IT', 'john', 'idro', 'B', 'saf', 1, 23);
```

Now you add a new column for the self-generated key:

```
ALTER TABLE tab ADD (index_tot_new varchar(255));
```

One way to generate an artificial key, that I think you've kind of proposed as part of your question, is to use the existing column values and concatenate them:

```
UPDATE tab 
SET index_tot_new = date || ';' || contract || ';' || nation || ';' || supplier ||';' || type1 ||';' || type2 ||';' || category || ';' || cat_weight|| ';' || index_tot
```

Thus, your new unique identifier (`index_tot_new`) for the first record will be `202101;8400A;IT;john;idro;B;saf;1;23`.

However, this would not be my preferred option of creating a unique identifier. Imagine, you change the table structure and add another field. This would essentially corrupt you whole index structure.

To me it feels like the easiest and least error-prone approach is to generate an UID for each record by using HANA function [NEWUID](https://help.sap.com/viewer/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/Cloud/en-US/fe7b7fede9aa4287ae69ffe3986e9c25.html):

```
UPDATE tab SET index_tot_new = NEWUID();
```

You could also think of using a series to generate a numeric ID, but it probably wouldn't add much benefit.